# kali linux stuck in log in after veil-evasion install

Tags: linux, boot, vmware, wine

I am running kali(4.3.0-amd64) guest in vmware.I need veil-evasion whose prerequities is wine32(if u don't know then just say it is an emulator to run window app).

The prorblem i'm facing is after installation of wine32 when i restart my kali guest it stucks at login.when password is correct the screen turns black like it is about to start but the revert back to login screen.

For wrong it simply shows incorrect password.

So what do i do ?